# Flash ActionScript 3 get auth info within single SWF

Tags: facebook, flash, security, actionscript

I am developing flash application as single `swf` file, without HTML wrapper (but for sure I have this swf located at my hosting). I have create application at developers section. The problem I have faced is: when I post this SWF to the my wall at FaceBook I can not get any call from this SWF of the `URLloader` or `ExternalItreface`.

For example, I need to do [Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) in order to get user information but I have got *Security Error* which say that my domain cannot get information from apps.facebook.com

The request I am doing is a simple:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://apps.facebook.com/my_app_name");
```

Is there any way to inform faceebok that my hosting is a security save?

Comment: The problem is that Flash requires a crossdomain.xml at the root of the (sub)domain for requests to work:

    http://apps.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml

gives a 404.

Comment: Yes, I have also found this issue. So, is there any way to get user info from single loaded into the wall SWF file?

Comment: You will not get a signed_request parameter anyway for something that is simple posted to a user’s wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grab things cross domain, the easiest way is to use a script on your server. If you're using php, you can easily connect to http://my.domain/my_script.php which can then CURL the info from http://apps.facebook.com/my_app_name or anywhere else.  You can then (parse and) pass that info to your swf.

Otherwise, you're going to need permission from the target to add a crossdomain rule for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have implement such workaround already but have no time to write a solution today, You beat me with this post :-). Some points to inform: yes, I use such proxy script on my server to get all what I need from FaceBook session if one exists and I do it by FaceBook official PHP SDK! Overall its simple - I use Open Graph to post a Flash on FaceBook wall (this is my application), then I do a request to my proxy script, then I get response with all logged in user info.